# Weird VGL Notice - [VGL] NOTICE: Pixel format of 2D X server does not match pixel format of Pbuffer. Disabling PBO readback

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glfw, optimus

I'm porting a game that I wrote from Windows to Linux. It uses GLFW and OpenGL. When I run it using optirun, to take advantage of my nVidia Optimus setup, it spits this out to the console:

```
[VGL] NOTICE: Pixel format of 2D X server does not match pixel format of
[VGL] Pbuffer.  Disabling PBO readback.
```

I've never seen this before, but my impression is that I'm loading my textures in GL_RGBA format, when they need to be in GL_BGRA or something like that. However, I'm using DevIL's ilutGLLoadImage function to obtain an OpenGL texture handle, so I never specify a format.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I have no idea what the answer to your specific question might be, but may I ask:  is there an interesting story behind your porting a game that you wrote from Windows to Linux?

Comment: I've been preparing to write a cross-platform game. I decided to port this game to Linux (as it's fairly small) as a study for part of that preparation. If you're interested, [this](http://github.com/drautb/snowman-apocalypse-linux) is the game I'm currently porting, and the game I intend to write later is [Greebles](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Games/Greebles.shtml).

Comment: I just got this message running an OGL context in SFML, was there a solution to the problem?

Comment: Not that I've been able to find. As a side note, however, I noticed that when I play Portal on Ubuntu, it spits out the same message. It doesn't seem to detract anything.

Comment: I have a same issue. optirun works well, but when I run dxdiag or any other DX9 wine program `optirun dxdiag` I got this notice, and nothing happens. No dxdiag window appears.

Comment: This is very likely just a notification that VGL cannot use a certain optimisation that could have been used had the pixel formats mentioned above matched.